# Kali Linux in VMware, Blinking cursor top-right, Black screen

Tags: linux, boot, vmware, kali-linux

[image: IMG:]

*The above animation shows what happened in booting (after it showed the grub menu, I hit 'Esc')!*
*I am really worried!*
*Please help me.*
*Neither apt update nor upgrade worked. And also modifying in grub didn't work at all.*
***All I Remember I Upgrading It, Then It Suddenly asked where to install grub There were Two options I Think it was '/dev/sda' and '/dev/sda1' (IF I AM NOT WRONG) I choose the sda1 option then it asked me "Do You Really Want To Skip Without Installing Grub" The cursor was on NO I Changed It To Yes I Thought I Don't Really need a Grub as There is only one Operating System Then I saw the grub while rebooting it and the Plymouth (This time booting really fast) but stuck with this screen so i started changing grub (Because only I remember is changing that and an 'apt autoremove') and now i got a dark blue standard Debian grub (I thought reinstalling grub would be helpful) but still negative results. I have Intel Virtualization turned on in bios. Still I Can't understand the Problem Please Help !!!...***
*I tried changing the `/etc/default/grub` file still negative.*
*Is there anyone who can help me. I can't just reinstall it.*
*All I Remember is upgrading (apt full-upgrade) my Kali which is in VMware*
***Also tried changing ram in VM Settings.***

Comment: Some suggestions:  (1) shut the machine down (2) VM settings:  3 GB of RAM, 1 CPU/ 2 cores, Display - turn off Accelerate 3D Graphics and make sure 1 monitor. (3) Start up the machine.

Comment: I Already Saw Your Comment but my PC is not working for some reason.So Please Try get more information for me Please. I Think I have enabled 3D Graphics and set the ram to 2 GB or I Think It was 2.5 GB of Ram with 4 Core Processors. I Gave It 3D acceleration to fix "the gnome animations not working problem". I thought it would fix it but id didn't. Really Thank you For Your Help. I Hope It Would Work

Comment: There is a VMware settings function (settings are in the .vmx file). Make sure that memory is 3GB.  Keep CPU to 1 CPU with 2 cores. I am not sure about 3D but do try disabling it to see (try it both ways). Power off the machine (force it off), make sure VMware is closed, restart the host computer and try running VMware and the machine again. I have used this technique before.

Comment: Thank You Actually I am CyberExploiter I deleted my account Cyber Exploiter so now i can only comment. But I happened to met with  this problem for the first time in my life . By the way Thank You So much It Did work

Comment: I will post the answer and hopefully you will acknowledge it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some suggestions that have worked for me before:

(1) Shut the machine down.

(2) VM settings: There is a VMware settings function in the VMware app Menu (settings are kept in the .VMX file).

(a) Memory: Make sure that memory is 3GB. Keep CPU to 1 CPU with 2 cores.

(b) Display: Turn off Accelerate 3D Graphics and make sure 1 monitor.  (try this setting both ways)

(3) Start up the machine and test.